# How do I translate this command into Python 3 language?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, command, pycharm

I want to translate this command into something that Python 3 can understand. I am using the WMI module (v1.4.9). In a command line, at this prompt:

> wmic:root\cli>

I would type this:

> /node:TargetComputerNameHere product get name, version, vendor

An IP address can be used to substitute TargetComputerNameHere, if one wanted to use that instead of the computer's name. Usually a domain administrator would be capable of doing this, but I tested it without administrator access in the Command Prompt, and I was able to run it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to express your command as something runnable from `cmd.exe` directly (like `wmic /node:TargetComputerNameHere product get name, version, vendor`) and then use:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(your_cmd_exe_command, shell=True, check=True)
```

Comment: How do I get it to read a command from cmd.exe? And would I save said command into a file to read from?

Comment: According to [this tutorial](https://betanews.com/2011/01/14/wmic-the-best-command-line-tool-you-ve-never-used/), the command from the answer may work as-is (also try `wmic /help` or `wmic /?`; personally, I use neither WMIC nor Windows). Then run `subprocess.run('wmic /node:TargetComputerNameHere product get name, version, vendor', shell=True, check=True)`.

Comment: It works (I replaced TargetComputerNameHere with an IP address that I set up), but now I want to make it so that it prints to a txt file I already made. I guess I would have to use some kind of redirect sign, but I tried using > and >> and neither worked.

Comment: @fread If this doesn't work even in `cmd.exe`, I guess you'd better ask a separate python-unrelated question on superuser.com.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Now I just have to modify it so that it writes it to a file that I already set up. I'll try to figure that out on my own.

Comment: Also, sorry I didn't see any of these comments, I was busy with other stuff last week.